# How to filter dataset to contain only specific keywords?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset which contains multiple countries.
How can I filter it so that it contains only specific countries?

[image]

For example now it contains UK, Belgium, France, ...etc

I would like to filter it so that it shows only France and Belgium.

So far I have tried that:

```
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset.Country == "France"].copy()
dataset.head()
```

and it works, because it filters only the data for France, but if I add Belgium

```
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset.Country == "France","Belgium"].copy()
dataset.head()
```

It doesn't work any more. 
I get the following error:

```
'the label [Belgium] is not in the [columns]'
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you want `dataset = dataset[dataset['Country'].isin([ "France","Belgium"])].copy()` what you tried is looking for a column `Belgium` which doesn't exist, the param after the comma looks for a column

Comment: Would something like `dataset = dataset.loc[dataset.Country == "France" or dataset.Country == "Belgium"].copy()` work? It's been a long time since I used pandas.

Answer (score 2):

what you tried failed because it's treating `'Belgium'` as a column to look for, which doesn't exist. If you want to filter against multiple values then use `isin`:

```
dataset = dataset[dataset['Country'].isin([ "France","Belgium"])].copy()
```

when you use `loc` the param after the comma is treated as the label to look for, in this case in the column axis